Typing of anonymous function in nested dicts
I have a nested dict like this
function_dict_1 = Dict(
    :f => Dict(
        :func1 => x -> x^2
    )
)

I want to call a strongly typed function, which receives this dict as an argument.
My first thought was to type it like this:
dict_arg::Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}}

However, I got an unmatched function call error.
I am confused, since it seems to work with other datatypes:
string_dict = Dict(
    :s => Dict(
        :string1 => "a"
    )
)
typeof(string_dict) <: Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, String}}
>> true

as well as with not-nested dicts:
function_dict_2 = Dict(
    :func1 => x -> x^2
)
typeof(function_dict_2) <: Dict{Symbol, <:Function}
>> true 

I tried the following types:

Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}}
Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, Function}}
AbstractDict{Symbol, AbstractDict{Symbol, <:Function}}
AbstractDict{Symbol, AbstractDict{Symbol, Function}}

which all did not work.
What is the correct way to type for this variable?

function_dict_1::Dict{Symbol, <:Dict{Symbol, <:Function}}

You could also solve this with an explicit generic parameter:
function_dict_1::Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, F}} where F <: Function

You're probably wondering why these both work when Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}} doesn't; after all, isn't Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}} the same as Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, F}} where F <: Function? No, because the implicit generic parameter is always scoped to the innermost {} containing the <:, so Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}} is actually the same as Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, F where F <: Function}}.
Now, except for tuples, T1 <: T2 does not imply that SomeType{T1} <: SomeType{T2}. So even though typeof(function_dict_1).parameters[2] is Dict{Symbol, var"#1#2"} (where var"#1#2" is the name of the type of the anonymous function), and Dict{Symbol, var"#1#2"} <: Dict{Symbol, <:Function} (but !(Dict{Symbol, var"#1#2"} <: Dict{Symbol, Function})!), we do not have that Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, var"#1#2"}} <: Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}}.
So why do the two answers I gave above work while Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}} doesn't? Because the implicit generic parameter is scoped to the innermost {} containing <:Function, the outer dict type is a concrete type, not a UnionAll.
julia> dump(Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}})
Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}} <: AbstractDict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, <:Function}}
  slots::Memory{UInt8}
  keys::Memory{Symbol}
  vals::Memory{Dict{Symbol, <:Function}}
  ndel::Int64
  count::Int64
  age::UInt64
  idxfloor::Int64
  maxprobe::Int64

Since function_dict_1 is not exactly this type, it cannot be a subtype of it.
Now, compare this to what we get for other types. For subtyping to work (except for tuples), we need either a UnionAll or an abstract type as the outermost type.
julia> dump(Dict{Symbol, <:Function})
UnionAll
  var: TypeVar
    name: Symbol #s66
    lb: Union{}
    ub: Function <: Any
  body: Dict{Symbol, var"#s66"<:Function} <: AbstractDict{Symbol, var"#s66"<:Function}
    slots::Memory{UInt8}
    keys::Memory{Symbol}
    vals::Memory{var"#s66"}
    ndel::Int64
    count::Int64
    age::UInt64
    idxfloor::Int64
    maxprobe::Int64

julia> dump(Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, F where F <: Function}})
Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, Function}} <: AbstractDict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, Function}}
  slots::Memory{UInt8}
  keys::Memory{Symbol}
  vals::Memory{Dict{Symbol, Function}}
  ndel::Int64
  count::Int64
  age::UInt64
  idxfloor::Int64
  maxprobe::Int64

julia> dump(Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, F}}  where F <: Function)
UnionAll
  var: TypeVar
    name: Symbol F
    lb: Union{}
    ub: Function <: Any
  body: Dict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, F<:Function}} <: AbstractDict{Symbol, Dict{Symbol, F<:Function}}
    slots::Memory{UInt8}
    keys::Memory{Symbol}
    vals::GenericMemory{:not_atomic, Dict{Symbol, F<:Function}, Core.AddrSpace{Core}(0x00)}
    ndel::Int64
    count::Int64
    age::UInt64
    idxfloor::Int64
    maxprobe::Int64

julia> dump(Dict{Symbol, <:Dict{Symbol, <:Function}})
UnionAll
  var: TypeVar
    name: Symbol #s67
    lb: Union{}
    ub: UnionAll
      var: TypeVar
        name: Symbol #s68
        lb: Union{}
        ub: Function <: Any
      body: Dict{Symbol, var"#s68"<:Function} <: AbstractDict{Symbol, var"#s68"<:Function}
        slots::Memory{UInt8}
        keys::Memory{Symbol}
        vals::Memory{var"#s68"}
        ndel::Int64
        count::Int64
        age::UInt64
        idxfloor::Int64
        maxprobe::Int64
  body: Dict{Symbol, var"#s67"<:(Dict{Symbol, <:Function})} <: AbstractDict{Symbol, var"#s67"<:(Dict{Symbol, <:Function})}
    slots::Memory{UInt8}
    keys::Memory{Symbol}
    vals::Memory{var"#s67"}
    ndel::Int64
    count::Int64
    age::UInt64
    idxfloor::Int64
    maxprobe::Int64

julia> 

In short, the first <: in Dict{Symbol, <:Dict{Symbol, <:Function}} is necessary to let the second <: make it out of its own {}, so that the whole type can be a UnionAll.
